# wear os 3: read data from blood oxygen saturation sensor

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os

I am developing an App for Wear OS 3, that needs to read blood oxygen saturation data ***on demand.***
The official android documentation, implies that you can do so using Health Services, using the data type **VO2_MAX**
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/health/services/client/data/DataType

However, no data is read, nor the sensor is available.
I checked that the SPO2 sensor is working, since I can used the wellness app installed by default in the smartwatc (I am using a Fossil Gen 6 with wear os 3)

I am using the [sample app provided](https://github.com/android/health-samples/tree/main/health-services/MeasureData), with a slight modification to read the data type VO2_MAX.
The code extract is below.
Is there another way of accessing this sensor?

Thank you!

```
    suspend fun hasHeartRateCapability(): Boolean {
        val capabilities = measureClient.getCapabilitiesAsync().await()
        return (DataType.VO2_MAX in capabilities.supportedDataTypesMeasure)
    }
```

```
             is MeasureMessage.MeasureData -> {
                    val vo2 = it.data.last().value
                    Log.d(TAG, "Data update: $%")
                    _voxMax.value = vo2
                }
```

Comment: were u able to find how to get SPO2? or other data from watch sensors

Answer (score 0):

Blood oxygen saturation is different from VO2 max. VO2 max is the volume of oxygen your body uses while exercising. And SPO2 is the blood oxygen saturation. Using Health services, we could only access VO2 data type and not SPO2. Might be possible with Google fit API

Comment: Thank you! Yo are right! I guess then that I need to start an exercise with wear os to access the VO2 data. To access the SPO2 I am going to check Google fit API as you suggest. My smartwatch (Fossil Gen 6) comes with a sleep track app installed (Wellness App), but I cannot see either how to extract the data (only visualize).